# Retain focus on element

Tags: javascript, html

On clicking of the **Log in** button, I get the alert message, however, on closing of the alert, the next focus is going back to the 1st textbox Username. I want the focus back on the button, so that I can tab to the next field.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Test </title>
    <script>
      function handleClick(){
        alert("welcome");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="aye" onSubmit="handleClick();">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" tabindex="0">
      <br>
      <input  type="submit" value="Log in" tabindex="0">
      <br>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" tabindex="0">
      <br>
    </form>
  </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can do a [`.focus()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) on an element using:

```
document.querySelector('yourselector').focus();
```

Like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Test </title>
    <script>
      function handleClick(){
        alert("welcome");
        document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').focus();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="aye" onSubmit="handleClick();">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" tabindex="0">
      <br>
      <input  type="submit" value="Log in" tabindex="0">
      <br>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" tabindex="0">
      <br>
    </form>
  </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: On closing of the alert box, I want the focus back on the 'Log in' button itself. I am not getting it.

Comment: Try to do the focus on the button. Change the selector to `input[type="submit"]`

Answer (score 0):

Using code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=submit]').focus();
    });
```

set focus on submit button.